# NSAppleScript and thread safety

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, thread-safety, applescript

My app needs to call pre-compiled AppleScripts periodically **on a background thread**. Because NSAppleScript is not thread-safe I need to execute the scripts on the main thread. I need to get the return value after executing the script so I am using this solution:

```
- (void) executeAppleScript:(NSMutableDictionary*) myDict
{
    NSString* returnValue = [[script executeAndReturnError:nil] stringValue];
    [myDict setValue:returnValue forKey:@"myKey"];

}

NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL error:nil];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(executeAppleScript:) withObject:myDict waitUntilDone:YES];
```

`script` is an instance variable. My question is, I am allocating `script` on the background thread and executing it on the main thread. Is allocation of NSAppleScripts thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> Because NSAppleScript is not
>   thread-safe I need to execute the
>   scripts on the main thread.

Answers this:

> Is allocation of NSAppleScripts
>   thread-safe?

No, it isn't safe.  In particular, the initialization of the instance could do any number of things that are not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't run into any problems yet but I didn't want to take the chance.

Comment: Have you tested on every make/model of Macintosh, across all CPU architectures, and across all versions of the OS (including ones that haven't been released yet)?  Until you can do that consistently, you have a ticking time bomb in your code....